# How to use default tenant when creating a company in Google Cloud Talent Solution (python)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-talent-solution

I can create companies  with:

```
client = talent_v4beta1.CompanyServiceClient()
company = {'display_name': ..., 'external_id: ...}
response = client.create_company('projects/my-project-id', company)
```

I don't specify a `tenant` and Google creates and uses a default tenant.

How do I call `get_company()`?

```
client = talent_v4beta1.CompanyServiceClient()
name = ?
response = client.get_company(name)
```

The only API I can find to populate `name` is `tentant_path()` which requires `tenant` to be passed in which I don't have the value for. If I call `project_path()` instead then this doesn't include any tentant and `get_company()` fails to match any companies.